# Validate HLSL file at compile time in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, shader, hlsl

I'm looking for an easy way of detecting errors in HLSL file at program compile time from visual studio. I want to add a custom build to my shader files that compiles them and make sure the build fail if I did something stupid like referring an undefined variable or other things that otherwise would be detected when compiling the shader in the application.

Have anyone successfully setup this before?

Comment: Solved it using fxc. Constructed a custom build step doing %25DXSDK_DIR%25\Utilities\bin\x86\fxc %(Identity) /E CSMain /T cs_5_0 /Fo $(TargetDir)/%(Identity).shader

Note that the /E and /T parameters needs to take the name of the entry point and the shader type in consideration.

Comment: +1 For the detail of the command @Laserallan! In my case I had to add quotes around `"%25DXSDK_DIR%25\Utilities\bin\x86\fxc.exe"`, but it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming by, here's a handy (and more wordy) guide on how to do it in VS2010:

http://takinginitiative.net/2011/02/19/debugging-hlsl/

Answer (score 3):

Note that VS2012 has automatic compilation of shader files.